# Google Analytics still reports "Tracking not installed" even though the code is on the web page

Tags: google-analytics

I added the code listed on the Tracking Info tab on the GA page.

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-26738353-3', 'smokingfishgames.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Unfortunately, for several hours now the GA tracking info shows an error message of `Status: Tracking Not Installed`.  I'm unsure why, considering that every few minutes when I refresh the page it says `Last checked:` with a very recent time.  I added the code to http://smokingfishgames.com, where it should be visible in the source exactly as shown above.

What am I doing wrong?  Did I just not wait long enough?  I've tried a bunch of solutions that were posted by other people, but many of them were extremely dated.

Very frustrating--I'm having the same issue with another web page.  Reports aren't being generated, either, so it's not a false alarm with the installation detection.

[image: GA Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot show that your code is `UA-26738353-2`, but your javascript snippet has UA-`26738353-3`.   It also indicates that the tracking for for imagedoku.com.   Make sure you are looking at the tracking info under the correct site in Google analytics, and that if you are, the tracking snippet that you are using matches.

---

You might have to wait up to a day before it says that it is receiving data and properly tracking.  If you just put the code on your website, try waiting.  It takes at least an hour, and up to a day.

---

I visited your site using Firefox with Live HTTP Headers and verified that the Google analytics script was actually fetched, followed by a call to Google analytics `/collect` url.  It looks like you are actually sending the data to Google.

---

The tracking snippet that you are using appears to the new "Universal Analytics (beta)" that Google is rolling out.  iain is reporting in the comments that they can't get Google to acknowledge that tracking is installed when using it.  I created a new site and was able to install it and verify that my site has tracking.    If it remains a problem, you you could try the old style asynchronous tracking:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-26738353-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'smokingfishgames.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: 1) I'm an idiot and screenshotted the wrong site--the same problem is happening on two sites, but I didn't screw up which analytics code snippet went on which site, just the screenshot.  2) Good call--the "last checked on:" thing was recent, but I wouldn't be surprised if that's bugged and the tracking isn't enabled yet.  Other people have said it can get that way.  3) *Phew* 4) I'll try that tomorrow, thanks!  I just copy/pasted the code that google analytics autogenerator gave me, but all the docs show the same snippet you show.

Comment: The code in the OP is the new Universal Analytics code, which is still in beta. Your code is the old version of GA. I was having the same problem with the UA code as the OP, but when I switched to the older code it went away

Comment: I just put the new "Universal Analytics" tracking in for a site I created.  I was able to get it tracking.  Given the beta nature of the new universal product, it is likely that Google has some bugs to work out.  I'll edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The code you're using is the new beta Universal Analytics code and I was having similar difficulties with it. My solution was to delete the account and create a new one using the older non-beta code and within seconds it was running fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue -- in my case it turned out that my logged-out homepage was using a different header file than the rest of the site, and I did not have the GA tracking code in the logged-out homepage header. I never noticed because the sole purpose of the logged-out homepage is to get people to log in, e.g. nobody uses it for anything interesting.

Oops.